# Getting error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: tf.browser.fromPixel is not a function

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow.js

i am using tensorflow js browser side this is the dependency

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
```

In the javascript this is what I am doing

```
let imageModelURL = "https://linktocode.com/model.json"
let htmlVideo = document.getElementById("video");
let model;

async function tensorFlow(){
  console.log("loading model")

  if (document.readyState !== 'complete') {
      console.log("dom not loaded")
    }

  model = await tf.loadLayersModel(imageModelURL);
  classifyVideo();

}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run);
function run()
{
  console.log("DOM Content Loaded")
  tensorFlow();
}

function classifyVideo() {
  console.log("classifying video")
  console.log(tf)
  console.log(tf.browser)
  console.log(tf.browser.fromPixel) //this is undefined

  let example = tf.browser.fromPixel(remoteVideo); //this throws error
  let prediction = model.predict(example);
  console.log(prediction)
  classifyVideo();
}
```

when thee above code is executed i get **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: tf.browser.fromPixel is not a function** Not sure why it is happening. I am not much experienced in tensorflow.js. Please let me know if there is anything I should add

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `tf.browser.fromPixels` not `tf.browser.fromPixel` as per the [documenation](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/1.0.0/#browser.fromPixels).